# How to translate entire site using the C# Google API?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

I don't get [this example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/)

```
  string text = "我喜欢跑步。";
    TranslateClient client = new TranslateClient(/* Enter the URL of your site here */);
    string translated = client.Translate(text, Language.ChineseSimplified, Language.English);
    Console.WriteLine(translated);
    // I like running.
```

It  "says enter the url of your site here". I thought that is the site you want to translate but then the next line takes in some text to translate. I don't get it. Do I first have to download the page somehow then translate it? Is there no translate entire page?

**Edit**

It does not seem possible. It also seems I have to pay for this library to use it. Is there any free ones out there?

Comment: According to the [API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#query-params) there doesn't seem to be a way to pass the API an URL and have it fetch and translate all text in the page, only chunks of text.

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question about free .NET translation libraries (if not already answered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL in question is the site that's running the code.  So if foo.com uses TranslateClient, "foo.com" should be the parameter.  The text is the actual text you want to translate, as shown in the example.

I don't *think* it will translate a URL the way the [web interface](http://translate.google.com/#en%7Ces%7Chttp://google.com) does, but I haven't tested.

**Also**, [the API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) is no longer available for free use, and it looks like [TranslateClient](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/source/browse/trunk/src/GoogleTranslateAPI/TranslateClient.cs) won't work for that, since it doesn't take a key.

You can look at whether the [website translator](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) would meet your needs.

Comment: Hmm I guess I am going to have to rethink how I am going to do this. Kinda sucks they don't allow you to do the whole page. I mean they have functionality.

Comment: I think the library is now a paid library only too now. I guess I have to find a totally new library.